# Put 3 text under one image

Tags: image, text, hyperlink

I have this image http://s23.postimg.org/on361znhn/Transform_Marketing.png
and I want to put 3 colored and centered (learn more) texts under each image. I tried this:

```
<p>
<span style="float:left;margin-left:100px;margin-right:40px"> <a href="my-website-url"></a> Learn More</span>
<span style="float:left;margin-left:170px;margin-right:40px"> <a href="my-website-url"></a> Learn More</span>
<span style="float:left;margin-left:120px;margin-right:40px"><a href="my-website-url"></a> Learn More</span>

</p>
```

but the link is not working. I want an option to change (learn more) text colour and font size and have it centered under each image.

Thank you for help.

Comment: put `Learn more` inside the anchor tag `<a></a>`, this will make your texts clickable

Comment: Thank you it works. do you have any idea on how to change text size, colour and make it centered under each image?

Answer (score 0):

to center each text below its image, the below code should help:

```
<div style="text-align:center; margin-right:5px; margin-left:5px;">
    <img src="img1.png"><br /><a href="url1">learn more</a>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center; margin-right:5px; margin-left:5px;">
    <img src="img2.png"><br /><a href="url2">learn more</a>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center; margin-right:5px; margin-left:5px;">
    <img src="img3.png"><br /><a href="url3">learn more</a>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Update (in case only one image):

You have to know the image width, adjust the text positions below the image using photoshop (you should use the same font & size you are using on the website).
Adjust the margins of your spans to center the text manually.

Comment: it's just one image but on this image i have 3 differents figures check it here : http://s23.postimg.org/on361znhn/Transform_Marketing.png

Comment: I thought the image was a screenshot from your website & the actual was 3 separate images. IMO, you should make them 3 separate images to have more control. If you don't wish to separate them, then check my updated answer.